# How to set flag to false after exception gets over or connection is established again

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using ExceptionListener to listen to any exceptions that may happen after connecting to IBM MQ. To know when the connection is down i am setting a flag to true in OnException Method.

This is because i dont want to put messages onto the queue when the connection is down. So basically, my requirement is to not send messages to the queue whenever the queue manager is down.

**I want to know how to set the flag to false after the the exception is resolved and the connection is back on**.

I know this is a very silly question but i am not able to figure it out.

This is my app.java file:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("Iteration : "+i);
            System.out.println(MQExceptionListener.flag + " FLAG");
            
           if(!MQExceptionListener.flag) {
                    producer.send(qName);
                }else {
                    continue;
                }       
            }           
        }
```

This is my connection config file:

```
@Bean
    public MQConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
        
        MQConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
        try {
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, false);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, user);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setConnectionNameList(connName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
        
    }
   
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> qm1JmsListenerContainerFactory(@Qualifier("mqQueueConnectionFactory") MQConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) throws InterruptedException {
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
      factory.setExceptionListener(new MQExceptionListener());
      configurer.configure(factory, mqQueueConnectionFactory);
      return factory;
    }
    
    @Bean("jmsTemplate1")
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(@Qualifier("mqQueueConnectionFactory") MQConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate1  = new JmsTemplate(mqQueueConnectionFactory);
        return jmsTemplate1;
    }
```

This is my Exception Listener File:

```
public class MQExceptionListener implements ExceptionListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQExceptionListener.class);

    static boolean flag = false;
     
    @Override
    public void onException(JMSException ex) {
        flag=true;
                        LOGGER.error(ex.toString());
                        if (ex.getLinkedException() != null) {
                            LOGGER.error(ex.getLinkedException().toString());
                        }
    }
}
```

This is my Output when i run my application:

```
Iteration : 0
false FLAG
In Listener 1
Received from qm1: Hi From Producer for QM1 with LISTENER
Iteration : 1
false FLAG
In Listener 1
Received from qm1: Hi From Producer for QM1 with LISTENER
```

When i end queue manager, i get the following exception every 5 seconds in a loop with iteration value, output :

```
2022-04-30 16:03:46.377  WARN 21484 --- [enerContainer-1] com.mq.sslMQ.MQExceptionListener         : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM5' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'Client'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
2022-04-30 16:03:46.377  WARN 21484 --- [enerContainer-1] com.mq.sslMQ.MQExceptionListener         : com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2059' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE')       
Iteration : 2
true FLAG
Iteration : 3
true FLAG
```

As you can see the flag becomes true when exception occurs. but after connecting as well the flag is true only.

So after starting the queue manager I want the flag to be set to false. Can you please guide, on how to set flag to false once exception gets over?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: I'm confused.  What is wrong with setting the flag to false after a successful connection?

Comment: Hi @Roger that is exactly what I want to do. But I am not sure where in the code exactly should I set it to false. How do I detect if connection has been successful and exception is over so that I can set the flag to false after that.

Answer (score 0):

Set the flag to `false` in your `BackOff` class.  This class is called just before the reconnect attempt.  If there is no exception, then the reconnect was successful and your flag will still be clear.

Comment: Hi @Doug Thanks for the suggestion but I am not adding a separate class for BackOff, I am extending FixedBackoff's class in my config class and i am using FixedBackOff by its object which i created in config class.